# Automapper 5.0.0 missing SourceValue (Custom Converters)

Tags: c#, automapper

After updating automapper version from 4.2.1 to 5.0.0 I got compilateion error that SourceValue  is missing.
Here is my example

```
 public class DraftLayoutCellPropertiesConverter : ITypeConverter<DraftLayoutCell, DraftGamePeriodDraftLayoutViewModel>
    {
        public DraftGamePeriodDraftLayoutViewModel Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var input = context.SourceValue as DraftLayoutCell;
            var result = new DraftGamePeriodDraftLayoutViewModel();

            if (input != null)
            {
```

What should be the replacement of that property? Is that the best way to do custom converters? I was expecting the update will not break existing code as there are many people using the app.

Answer (score 5):

In Automapper 5, The interface `ITypeConverter` changed, you need to update your implementation:

```
public class DraftLayoutCellPropertiesConverter : ITypeConverter<DraftLayoutCell, DraftGamePeriodDraftLayoutViewModel>
{
    public DraftGamePeriodDraftLayoutViewModel Convert(DraftLayoutCell source, DraftGamePeriodDraftLayoutViewModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var input = source;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I can see, the `ITypeConverter` has the following declaration:

```
public interface ITypeConverter<in TSource, out TDestination>
{
    TDestination Convert(TSource source, ResolutionContext context);
}
```

And it looks like you have wrong implemented this interface.

Once you have implemented it properly, you can use `TSource source` parameter to get access to you `SourceValue`.

About your question 'Is that the best way to do custom converters`: if you need to use the custom`converter` then you definitely need to implement interface above for it. However, it depends on your case and sometimes you might need to use custom value provider which could be used kind like a converter.